# Calculate the volumes of cube cut by a parametrized surface

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have a 2D-surface embedded in a 3d-volume for example the surface of a sphere,
which is defined by r² = x² + y² + z². Now I want to calculate the volumes generated by the cut of this surface within a cube. As an example see this image
[image]

So in this case one volume would be simply V = 4/3 πr³/8 = π/8 ~ 0.5239,
 what would be a fast way to calculate this numerically with high accuracy?
My first idea was to use a simple monte-carlo method which seems to work but is not fast enough since I have to repeat this procedure for around 1000 cubes. For example:

```
import numpy as np

def get_pi(n):
    k = 10000
    m = n/k
    result = 0
    for i in range(m): #split up n to save memory
        x = np.random.rand(k)
        y = np.random.rand(k)
        z = np.random.rand(k)
        r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)
        t = r<1
        result += np.sum(t)/float(k)*6
    result /=m
    return result

In [19]: get_pi(100000000)-np.pi
Out[19]: -9.6033589800370578e-05

In [28]: %timeit get_pi(100000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.98 s per loop
```

Is there maybe a better algorithm or at least a way to make this faster?
Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: In general this should work for all kinds of surfaces with a given parametrization like the type of above. Also the cube could have a different position than the origin.

Comment: see a recent answer on codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69370/monte-carlo-pi-calculation/69381#69381

Comment: Would a symbolic calculation also be satisfactory?

Comment: @Oliver W.: If it's possible, sure why not.

Comment: @jsrm, well I checked with sympy, but it's definitely not as fast as the vectorized Monte Carlo approach suggested here (and that's for this relatively simple surface already). Eickenberg has proposed a good solution, but it's too specific: only works for a sphere encased by a cube (same origin, diameter=side). But that's because of the problem description: in general it is not easy to find a test method to see if a point is within a volume described by a surface. You'll also need to specify e.g. which side of the surface makes up the volume (think of conic sections here).

Comment: Perhaps you could append to your question more info about the type of these surfaces. `f(x) + f(y) + f(z)` is good, but it's not enough. One could still think of a whole slew of possible surfaces made up by that equation. Oh, by the way did you mean `f(x) + g(y) + h(z)`?

Comment: Yes I did, in general the surfaces will not be to difficult,for example a cylinder / a cube rotated by 45 degress etc. So every Surface can be defined by a Masking function, also the cell size will be small compared to the curvature of the Surface.